# Javascript detect if html elements fit screen

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to use javascript to detect if html content can't fit the screen (is scrollable) to show a "back to top button" only if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use jQuery, you could try finding the window height and comparing it to a wrapper element height.  If the element height is greater, show the button.

```js
var x = $(window).height();
if ($('#test').height() > x) {
  alert('scrollable');
  //add in button here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="height:2000px;background:silver"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, but perhaps you could get the element using `document.getElementById()`, then use `innerHeight` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp) to determine if the element exceeds the height.

Edit - seems like I might have misread a bit.  If you want to check the entire HTML content on the page, you can use something like `scrollHeight` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) on `document`.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the height of the page to the height of your browser:

```
document.body.offsetHeight < screen.availHeight
```

That will return true if the page fits. Although for your purpose, why not just show the button if the user is scrolled down at all? Assuming you can use jQuery,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document.body).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        //Add or show button here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not IE supported, but my fave vanilla javascript is always:

```
var scrollHeight = window.scrollY;
console.log(scrollHeight);
```